# Why is validation accuracy fluctuating between two extremes?

Tags: classification, lstm, multilabel

I am using a LSTM to make a multi-label classifier. However the problem is, the validation accuracy fluctuates between 0.7 and 0.3. I have about 4367 samples (80-20 validation split) and 240 sample length.

[image]

My current model is quite simple, just 1 LSTM layer and 1 output layer. I have tried with more complex models for e.g. increasing LSTM layers, Dense layers, adding dropout but the accuracy plot looks very similar. What am I missing here? Will it be ok if I just pick the higher accuracy fit?

```
def lstmModel(features, seq_length, numClasses):
  init_learning_rate = 0.1
  model = Sequential()

  model.add(LSTM(512,input_shape=(seq_length,features),return_sequences=False)) 
  model.add(Dense(numClasses,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='sigmoid'))    
  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=init_learning_rate) 
  model.summary()
  model.compile(loss='BinaryCrossentropy',optimizer =optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```